# How many ways to assign 3 types of treatments to 60 mice?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose there are drugs A, B and a control group. 
Drug A is given to 22 mice, drug B is given to another 22 mice, and the remaining 16 mice are a control group.

How many ways can the assignment of treatment to mice be made? (Single assignment involves specifying treatment for each mouse - whether drug A, drug B, or no drug)

My attempt:
C(60,22) * C(60,22) * C(60,16)

would this work?

Comment: A correct version of your idea would be $\binom{60}{22}\binom{38}{22}\binom{16}{16}$, where the $\binom{16}{16}$ can be left out since it is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost correct, you need to use the [multinomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html)

The amount of combinations are:
$${60 \choose 22,22,16}=\frac{60!}{22!22!16!}$$
Which is equivalent to:
$${60 \choose 22,22,16}=\frac{60!}{22!22!16!}=\frac{60!}{38!22!}\frac{38!}{22!16!}\frac{16!}{16!0!}={60 \choose 22}{38 \choose 22}{16 \choose 16}$$